# Accessing folder outside the website directory in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, virtual-directory, shared-directory

I have around 20 websites created a single `web-server,` now i have made a tool which will be common for all the websites, so i have a common user-control, which i am using on .aspx file inside all the website

Now i want to keep these user-controls in a location outside the website directory so that i can access these same control to all the websites.

However i cannot find a way to get the directory outside the website's root directory.

I googled around and saw the option to make the directory as virtual one, so that it will be accessible to the site, but here i would have to link the folder to one website at a time, so it would be same keeping controls in separate websites, which i want to avoid for update reasons.

Can anyone tell me how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Hi In rough unchecked code something like:

You can access like this.

```
webRootPath = Server.MapPath("~")
docPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(rootPath, "..\Documents/MyDocument.xml"))
```